# Explicit form of one isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$, $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$. What is the explicit coordinate-free form of the canonical isomorphism $$\mathrm{\mathop{Hom}}(\mathrm{\mathop{Hom}}(V, W), k) = \mathrm{\mathop{Hom}}(W, V)?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A:V\to W$ then $A$ gives a linear map $a:Hom(W,V)\to k$ via $a(B)=Tr(AB)$. That's it.